# allowing user input only certain numbers , only integers , in C#?

Tags: c#

So I  am making a console application that uses a "switch" statement , and i want to let the user input only integers and numbers from 1 to 3 for the switch statement , what i have until now is :

```
 while ((!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out alegere)))
            {
                    Console.Write("Wrong , input again :  ");
            }
```

but this will put the user input the choice again only if its not an integer and i need to put a restriction on the interval which contain the number like i said before only certain numbers like 1 , 2 and 3

Comment: use a conditional.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the number range check as well in it:

```
while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out alegere) || (alegere  < 1 || alegere >3 ) )
{
      Console.Write("Wrong , input again :  ");
}
```